# QGIS sum selected line lengths

Tags: qgis, vector, line, select, summarizing

I need a tool which displays the sum of selected lines as I go in QGIS. Something like the Measure line-tool. I´m new to PyQGIS. The logic seems quite simple, I just don´t know where to start. I guess this could be a good starting point https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211162/161290?

Comment: Since you post a link to the answer to your question, will you close your question yourself? Or will you describe, how that answer doesn't suite your needs?

Comment: That´s an old answer and to my knowledge there has been changes in the API. I do not know what changes need to be made to the code to make it work. The linked answer does not work as it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is using the Field Calculator to create a label that show the sum of the selected lines.

In the lines layer create a label using the expression

```
array_sum(aggregate(
 layer:= 'line',
 aggregate:='array_agg',
 expression:=$length,
 filter:=is_selected()))
```

**NB:** To use `array_sum` in the oldest QGIS versions you need to install the plugin *arrayPlus*.

This will create a label with the sum of the selected lines. It will appear in all the lines.

Since QGIS 3.10 in the label is integrated a Geometry Generator: you can use it to move the label to the centre of the screen or in a preferred position.

In the Layer Styling > Label Panel go to the Geometry Generator and use the variable

`@map_extent_center` and select the Point / Multipoint geometry option

this will move a single label to the centre of you Canvas. [image]

If you want you can play with colour , background and offset to move your label.
This is an example integrating the original expression with a text.

Here the modified expression:

```
concat( 'Total length: ',
array_sum(aggregate(
 layer:= 'line',
 aggregate:='array_agg',
 expression:=(format_number($length,3)),
 filter:=is_selected()))
,' m')
```

[image]

Comment: There is no function named array_sum. Which version are you using? Otherwise this is exactly the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I am using 3.10. Sorry, my bad. To use ```array_sum``` you need to install the plugin *ArrayPlus* that integrated some extra array to your system. I will correct the answer.

Comment: Everything's working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with the answer can you please vote and accept it. Thanks.