# Advanced labeling in QGIS to automatically get data from new fields and create arrays

Tags: qgis, python, labeling, array, advanced-python-field-calculator

I'd like to be able to easily get quick data from different projects I work in in order to avoid having to do sql queries all the time. So here's the thing, today I managed to get the following expression working fine using some advanced labeling settings in QGIS. I used this as a guide: [QGIS sum selected line lengths](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357546/qgis-sum-selected-line-lengths)

```
concat('Longitud total: ',round(array_sum(aggregate(
layer:= 'streetaxis longtotal_fix',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:=$length,
filter:=is_selected())),2),' m')
```

It simply returns the sum of the lengths of the selected entities of a defined line layer. Then I configured the label's position to fix it in the top-left corner. I am aware it's kinda a sloppy way to do that, but it does the job and it is certainly a quick and efficient solution for me.
[image]

Now I'd like to do something more advanced following the same method for a different layer (a points layer). First, I'd like to get the sum of several fields individually. I highligthed the fields I am referring to on the table screenshot below. These fields name always begin with "pre_" and they are automatically created and updated on a quarterly basis in the database. So, I can't just put the name of each field in the script.

[image]

So far I got this simplified code working for just one field:

```
array_sum(aggregate(
layer:= 'aigues_consums',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:=coalesce(per_201903,0),
filter:=is_selected()))
```

Note: I had to use coalesce because of NULL values, which prevented the expression to work when a point with null data was selected.

[image]

What it does right now is return the sum of the "per_201903" field for the selected points. So, I'd like to get the data for each field and then to display them independently. Since all the fields I want to get the data from begin with "per_, I had in mind using some function to easily detect the fields which their names contain "per_", but I don't know how to do this - or even if it is possible. I suspect it can be done combining it with array_foreach function, and creating a concatenated variable to increase year (+1) and month (+3),but this definitely surpasses my current knowledge of QGIS.

For example, I am looking for an output like this:

per_201903: 452 
per_201906: 652 
per_201909: 422 
per_201912: 395 
per_202003: 488 
per_202006: 680 
[etc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use this expression to get an array with all fieldnames starting with `per_`:

   ```
   array_filter( 
       map_akeys(attributes()),
       left (@element,4)='per_'
   )
   ```

   - `attributes()` gets a map of all fieldnames:values - [see docu](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#attributes)
   - `map_akeys` returns an array of all fieldnames - [see docu](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=attributes#map-akeys)
   - `array_filter()` to keep only fieldnames starting with 'per_' - [see docu](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=attributes#array-filter)
2. Now for each of these fieldnames (elements of this array), run your expression separately, using `array_foreach()` .
3. To run your expression for each of these fieldnames, create the expression as a string and access the varying fieldnames with `@element` (this inserts the values of the elements from the array of step 2) by concatenating `@element` and the rest of the expression with  pipes `||` to get everything in one string . Then convert this string to a working expression with `eval()`:

```
array_foreach(
    array_filter( 
        map_akeys(attributes()),
        left (@element,4)='per_'
    ),
    eval (
        'array_sum(
            aggregate(
                layer:= ''your_layer_name'',
                aggregate:=''array_agg'',
                expression:='  || @element  || ',
                filter:=is_selected()
            )
        )'
    )
)
```

*Remark: inside the `eval()` function, you need to define the expression as a string, defined by single quotes `'`. As the expression that should be evaluated contains itself a string (`'your_layer_name'`), you must mask the single quotes here so that QGIS understands that the string used to be evaluated by `eval` is not over. Use two single quotes `''` (not double quotes `"`) for masking.*

[image]

*Visualizing the sum for all selected points (yellow) of the values of all fields starting with `per_`; selected points are additionally labeled with their individual values:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this defenitly saved me. The only thing is that, since selections with null values didn't appear, I had the delete the array_sum() function and change the aggregate argument for aggregate:=''sum'

Comment: Great, good that you could solve the null values